# TFS2015 Update 1 OLAP warehouse not working anynmore

Tags: tfs, olap, olap-cube, tfs-2015

It seems that there is a problem with TFS 2015 Cubes.

When you run the Test Plan Dimension than it complains about:
 Errors in the high-level relational engine. The following exception occurred while the managed IDbCommand interface was being used: Invalid column name 'PlanOwner__SID'.
Invalid column name 'PlanOwner__Name'..

Strange thing is that I have recreated the databases and it continues to have this problem.

Comment: I have the same issue. How did you solve it?

Comment: I received this error when I had a view that referenced another database that did not exist. I placed a copy of the missing database on the server and the problem was fixed.

Answer (score 0):

The Database TFS_warehouse collect data from TFS_Configuration and TFS_ProjectCollection. And the Database TFS_Analysis base on the TFS_warehouse.

There is a easy way to solve the error. Delete the Database TFS_warehouse and TFS_Analysis. Then recreate it. [How to recreate the Data warehosue and the Analysis service for TFS?](https://mohamedradwan.wordpress.com/2010/10/29/how-to-recreate-the-data-warehosue-and-the-analysis-service-for-tfs/)

Then you need to reconfigure TFS reporting service with the new Database. However, the new Database is empty. You need to [manually process the TFS data warehouse and analysis services cube](https://msdn.microsoft.com/Library/vs/alm/Report/admin/manually-process-data-warehouse-and-cube) to make the reporting service works right now.

Comment: I will try it on monday. now I did already try to recreate the databases. maybe I made a mistake so I ll try again following this post.

Thank You